# Problema com Loops no Javascript

Tags: javascript

Ola, estou com um problema em loops porem nao tenho ideia do que possa ser:

Segue o jsfiddle: [Link Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5ygp76d/)

```
    function seleciona(){
        
        var inicio = sini.value;
        var fim = sfim.value;
        
        console.log("Inicia pintura");
        console.log(inicio + " " + fim);
        while(inicio < fim){
    
            console.log("Existe item " + inicio);   
            inicio ++;
            
        }
        
    }
```

Nesse codigo, eu removi a parte que faz a pintura dos elementos da pagina pela questao de com eles ou sem eles o erro continua do mesmo jeito, parece ser algo no loop e nao no codigo dentro do loop.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que acontece, esse código pega dois valores de dois inputs, um valor inicial e um valor final que seria um intervalo de datas de um calendário, foi numerado os dias do ano de 1 a 365, o problema é que quando jogo os valores nesse loop, tanto o while como o for, nao funcionam perfeitamente, normalmente as primeiras tentativas nao funcionam....depois funciona, pra conferir coloquei um log pra exibir os valores no console, e sempre os valores sao exibidos certinho, nao da erro algum, a sensação que tenho é como se os valores nao estao chegando no loop para fazer a comparação, alguem consegue me da uma ideia?

Nessa imagem nota-se no log...que os dados sao recebidos porem o loop nao executa e ja em outra tentativa funciona, ja tentei um intervalo menor ou outro maior, mas sempre é uma falha intermitente.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como essa função `seleciona` é chamada? Qual é o escopo das variável `sini` e `sfim`?

Comment: Depois de escolhido o segundo valor no calendario a funcao e chamada, sini e sfim, no momento coloquei como global...mas antes estava no escopo da funçao, mas nao me atentei muito para isso, pois a funcao seleciona esta sendo executada, os logs estao funcionado, os dados das variaveis estao chegando, mas o loop nao esta executando.

Answer (score 0):

Ola, consegui resolver, quando seleciono as datas, as informacões vão para os inputs de texto, essas informações são o dia inicial e o final, depois a função "seleciona" é executada para colorir o intervalo entre as duas datas, eu não sei bem o que estava acontecendo, mas foi resolvido fazendo uma conversão em inteiro dos dados pegos nas inputs para depois processar nos loops, sem a conversão dessas informacoes, os dados as vezes não eram comparados, mesmo sendo números o conteúdo das inputs o JavaScript nao fazia a comparação.